# Complex Analysis Problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image under the map f(z) = $ e^{iz} $ of the square

S = {z $\in$ $C$ | 0 $\leq$ Re(z) $ \leq $ 1, 1 $\leq$ Im(z) $\leq$ 2}

and label the corresponding portions of the boundary.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths are relatively straightforward ; the bottom of the square is given by:

$z(t)=t ; 0\leq t\leq1 $  Then the image of the bottom of the square is $e^{it}=cost+isint$.

Now, parametrize the other sides of the rectangle and do the same process.